# Unknown exception from std::promise

Tags: c++, c++11, promise, c++14, future

What is wrong with the following code?  When ran the program aborts with an unknown exception

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

int main() {
    auto promise = std::promise<int>{};
    auto future_one = promise.get_future();
    promise.set_value(1);

    return 0;
}
```

The error output is

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1
Aborted (core dumped)
```

`g++ --version` for me gives

```
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The same code works just fine on a mac

---

**Note** The line of code that the exception originates from is the `promise.set_value(1)`

Comment: @vu1p3n0x an empty shared state should not imply that the next get_future will throw.  Also its the set_value which throws here for some reason..

Comment: Put a debugger on the thing and figure out exact what is throwing that exception. There's nothing wrong with the code, and I can't reproduce the reported exception on Wandbox's GCC 5.4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In short, adding `-pthread` resolves your issue.

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 -g -pthread -o temp temp.cpp
$ ./temp
```

---

## Details

I can reproduce the behavior on Ubuntu 16.04 with below command on compiling:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 -g -o temp temp.cpp
$ ./temp
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1
Aborted (core dumped)
```

GDB dump shows:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff74ab428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
#1  0x00007ffff74ad02a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff7ae484d in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7ae26b6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7ae2701 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff7ae2919 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff7b0b7fe in std::__throw_system_error(int) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x000000000040259b in std::call_once<void (std::__future_base::_State_baseV2::*)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*, bool*), std::__future_base::_State_baseV2*, std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*, bool*>(std::once_flag&, void (std::__future_base::_State_baseV2::*&&)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*, bool*), std::__future_base::_State_baseV2*&&, std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*&&, bool*&&) (__once=...,
    __f=<unknown type in /home/mine/tempdir/temp, CU 0x0, DIE 0xe578>) at /usr/include/c++/5/mutex:746
#8  0x0000000000401e06 in std::__future_base::_State_baseV2::_M_set_result(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>, bool) (this=0x61ac30, __res=..., __ignore_failure=false) at /usr/include/c++/5/future:387
#9  0x0000000000402aee in std::promise<int>::set_value(int&&) (this=0x7fffffffe1c0, __r=<unknown type in /home/mine/tempdir/temp, CU 0x0, DIE 0xeb8a>) at /usr/include/c++/5/future:1075
#10 0x0000000000401759 in main () at temp.cpp:7
```

From the dump, we can see it's using mutex, etc.
Then I realize that `std::future` stuff depends on thread, so it needs to link against `pthread`, otherwise we see this exception.

The same for `std::thread`

Comment: wow, i should have remembered that you need the `-pthread` flag on many systems