# std::promise<void> throws Unknown error, unless calling sleep

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I have this code:

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::promise<void> p;
    p.set_value();
    p.get_future().get();

    return 0;
}
```

And after compiling it with `gcc` it throws `std::system_error`:

```
$ g++ -o foo foo.cpp -std=c++11 -lpthread
$ ./foo
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1
```

What is weird, adding zero-second sleep **before** creating the promise, prevents the exception:

```
int main()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(0));
    std::promise<void> p;
    p.set_value();
    p.get_future().get();

    return 0;
}

$ g++ -o foo foo.cpp -std=c++11 -lpthread
$ ./foo
$
```

I tried `gcc` 4.8.5 and 5.4.0, same results. Why does it behave like that?

Comment: I cant reproduce it: https://wandbox.org/permlink/FDfl2jIkEeAXIbKj

Comment: Is there any reason you felt the need to omit the version of GCC you can reproduce this on? Kind of important information...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown exception from std::promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928715/unknown-exception-from-stdpromise)

Comment: It is wrong to build with `-lpthread`. You should with `-pthread`.

Comment: @ks1322 thanks, it seems that it was about `lpthread` vs `pthread`

Comment: @user167921 updated the exact versions

Comment: @TomaszMaciejewski I've edited your question back. On StackOverflow we avoid to answer the question in the question itself ;).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error comes from your compilation. It should be:

```
 g++ -o foo foo.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread
```

The `<thread>` library needs this special flag `-pthread` but you provided `-lpthread`. The former compile your translation unit with the full thread support. The later only links the library, without defining the needed macros and needed tools.

On coliru:

- with `-pthread`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a53bed6696bb8d83
- without: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd972e1556f8c060

Comment: @infinitezero it might be due to my first version which was unperfect (was it worth a downvote though, who knows?).