# Cause of std::system_error

Tags: c++

My attempt to write a thread pool implementation has stalled out because of issues with the function template responsible for submitting tasks to the pool itself.

I've reduced the code down to its most basic components: creating a `std::promise` object, assigning to it, and returning its `std::future` object, and I'm still getting the error.

```
#include<future>
#include<iostream>

template<typename Func, typename Ret>
void set(std::promise<Ret> & promise, Func && func) {
    promise.set_value(func());
}

template<typename Func>
void set(std::promise<void> & promise, Func && func) {
    func();
    promise.set_value();
}

template<typename Func, typename ... Args>
auto execute(Func && func, Args && ... args) ->
std::future<decltype(func(args...))> {
    using Ret = decltype(func(args...));
    std::promise<Ret> promise;
    set(promise, [&]{return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);});
    return promise.get_future();
}

void reverse(std::string & string) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < string.size() / 2; i++)
        std::swap(string[i], string[string.size() - 1 - i]);
}

int main() {
    try{
        std::string string = "Hello World!";
        auto future2 = execute(reverse, string);
        future2.get();
        std::cout << string << std::endl;
    } catch(std::system_error const& e) {
         std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
         std::cerr << e.code() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Console Output:

```
Unknown Error: -1
generic: -1
```

From debugging, the error appears to occur exactly at the moment I call `set_value` on the `promise` object; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`std::system_error::code()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error/code) might be helpful to check what exactly had gone wrong.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If I do `std::cerr << e.code() << std::endl;` I get `generic: -1`.

Comment: Did yoiu check the call stack information?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As i said in the post, the error occurs at the moment I call `set_value()` on the `promise` object.

Comment: I got `!dlroW olleH` with `g++ 8.2.1`...

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm getting the error with the compiler found here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler I don't know what compiler they're using.

Comment: @Xirema It is G++ 5.4.1, info from FAQ link. Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928715/unknown-exception-from-stdpromise (the same `unknown error -1` on 5.4 version).

Comment: https://ideone.com/myWO6K seems to work. On https://rextester.com/XOC22143 it fails with g++ 5.4, but works with clang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unknown reasons, this error appears to be caused by failing to include GCC's thread library, `pthread`. Compiling the program by adding the `-pthread` flag causes the error to go away.